# PDFKit - PDFPage.characterBounds(at: Int) returns wrong character bounds with iOS 17 beta 5

Tags: ios, pdf, ios-pdfkit, ios17

Apple's PDFKit function `PDFPage.characterBounds(at:)` returns wrong character bounds running iOS 17 beta 5 / Xcode 15 beta 6 while returning correct data running iOS 16 (or earlier).

Has anybody experienced the same issue and/or has found a workaround on iOS 17 beta?

Filed feedback to Apple (FB12918701).